Efficient random outage simulation using Pandas
I'm trying to generate a random sequence of outages for a set of industrial plants.
An individual plant can be either online, or offline. I need to generate a time-series for each plant showing it's availability (0 = offline, 1 = online).
Each plant has characteristic data giving its mean outage duration (in days, usually around 3), and the mean fraction of time it is offline in any given duration (in %, around 5%).
I have a solution using native Python, which draws a series of outage lengths and days between outages, both from geometric distributions. However, this is quite slow when generating many series. Is there a way I can use Pandas to speed this up?
mean_outage_length = 3
forced_outage_derating = 0.95
# Forced Outage Derating is percentage of time you would expect a plant to be online allowing for unplanned outages only

outage_length_mu = np.log(1 - 1 / (mean_outage_length + 1))
between_outages_probability = (1 - forced_outage_derating) * (1 / (mean_outage_length + 1)) / (forced_outage_derating)
        
if between_outages_probability >= 0.9999999999999999:
    between_outages_mu = -40
else:
    between_outages_mu = np.log(1 - between_outages_probability)

sum_of_days = 0
days_in_between_outages = []
outage_lengths = []
days_in_simulation_window = 1000        

while True:
    outage_length = math.floor(np.log(1 - random.random()) / outage_length_mu)
    days_until_next_outage = math.ceil(np.log(1 - random.random()) / between_outages_mu)
            
    if first_pass:
        first_pass = False
        if random.random() > forced_outage_derating:
            days_until_next_outage = 0

    sum_of_days += (days_until_next_outage + outage_length)

    if sum_of_days > days_in_simulation_window:
        break

    outage_lengths.append(outage_length)
    days_in_between_outages.append(days_until_next_outage)
        
    if sum_of_days - outage_length <= days_in_simulation_window:
        days_in_between_outages.append(days_until_next_outage)
        outage_lengths.append((days_in_simulation_window - (sum_of_days - outage_length)) + 1)


Expected Output:
Given a set of N plants, with each plant having a mean outage length, and expected fraction of time online, return a set of outage lengths and durations between outages.
e.g.
Input:
Simulation Duration: 100 days
Plant A: Mean outage length - 5 days, fraction of time online - 80%
Plant B: Mean outage length - 3 days, fraction of time online - 90%
Output:
Plant A: Outage Durations - [3, 7, 6, 4], Duration between outages - [15, 25, 30, 10]
Plant B: Outage Durations - [2, 5, 3], Duration between outages - [35, 15, 40]

Your example is missing a lot of variables to be reproducible, also it would be great to provide a short example/description of the expected output

@mozway Edited to improve reproducibility

thanks but please also better explain the logic and expected output

@mozway edited to include a short example and output

Can you include reproducible code? For example, what is first_pass initialized to?

You seem to be using whole days as the basic unit of time. Is there a particular reason for that? Most industrial organizations I've dealt with don't count it as a whole day lost to downtime if things get restored within a few hours.
